# Why do tags look less fancy in review filters?

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, design

While attempting to filter the First Posts queue by tags, I noticed that they don't have the same fancy style as they do everywhere else on the site.

> ## Review queue tag filter
>
> [image]

> ## User page (an example of *everywhere else*)
>
> [image]

Could the tags in the filter box be given the same styling?